# In a fair deck of 52 cards, how many 5 card hands contain the ace of spades?

Tags: probability

is the answer 51 Choose 4?

assuming all possible combinations of hands are equal to (52 Choose 5)

Comment: Right, because you are choosing 4 cards without replacement from 51, and order does not matter

Comment: Your answer of $\binom{51}{4}$ is right. We don't need to assume all hands are equally likely. But we do need to do that if we want to compute the *probability* that the hand contains the Ace of spades.

Comment: Ok then can you tell me why the Probability of getting a random hand of 5 cards with exactly one ace is NOT equal to

(51 Choose 4) / (52 Choose 5) @AndréNicolas

Comment: The Ace can be any one of the $4$ Aces. And the rest of the cards have to be non-Aces. So the number of such hands is $\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4}$.

Comment: ah thank you, is there any way of giving you credit for this answer?

Comment: You are welcome. Credit is of no importance.